# How do you open a remote powershell session on an EC2 instance in a private subnet on AWS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, powershell

It's possible to open a remote powersheel session when the AWS instance has a public IP (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21920773/execute-powershell-script-remotely-on-amazon-ec2-instance-from-my-local-computer).

Can you do the same on a server in a private subnet using a NAT? (and not a jumpbox or bastion server)

Answer (score 1):

A NAT is for outgoing connections, not incoming, so no a NAT will not enable public connections into your private subnet. You'll need a bastion host in your public subnet.

Comment: I see. Thanks. So, is it possible to remote powershell into the bastion server, then within that remote session, remote into the private server? I'm trying to avoid using RDP

Comment: I don't know the answer to your follow-up question sorry, I know nothing about powershell. What you describe is how you'd do it with SSH on a unix machine.

Comment: @jbd I'd recommend setting up the PowerShell web access feature on your public bastion server and then using that to access private hosts. If you remote into the bastion server via PowerShell you will run into the second hop issue with other hosts you try to access and will need to setup CredSSP.